# Finding a word tree translater for sentences that does all the work for me

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I am not an expert in linguistics.  I want to know if there is a site or a program that will allow me to put in complex sentences of novels that I read , then answer with a word tree labeling the various components of the sentence and there relationship to each other, so I have a better idea of what is going on linguistically and semantically. Something that basically does all the work for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Weblicht](http://weblicht.sfs.uni-tuebingen.de/weblichtwiki/index.php/Tools_in_Detail#Syntax_-_Parsers_and_Chunkers) offers such a service for German and English to the academic community. In order to use it, you need an Academic Account for Fedarated login in a participating European country or you need to be enrolled in the CLARIN IdP.

Note that the tools behind the service are often free tools and can be downloaded from their respective URLs (Search for Stanford Parser, Stuttgart Parser, or Berkeley Parser) and used from the command line.